# The iPhone app closes immediately when I open the map

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, google-maps, sdk

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

full description

Comment: flutter sdk 2.10.3

Comment: google_maps_flutter: ^2.1.3

Comment: Your code is sending an `objectForKey` request to a string - in other words, there is an object that is a string, but your code is expecting a dictionary

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Use Google Maps when you open the map on the iPhone, the application closes, and this reason appears in the console

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/102204#issuecomment-1104860970

Comment: Do not modify your question to include the answer. The Question field is for the _question_.  If you have an answer it goes in the Answer field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the google map API key on ios/Runner/AppDelegate.swift file

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import GoogleMaps

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
    override func application(
        _ application: UIApplication,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
    ) -> Bool {
        GMSServices.provideAPIKey("GOOGLE_API_KEY")
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
        return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    }
}
```

Comment: i added it you can see here on githube i open issue

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/102204#issuecomment-1103795753